# Deserialise Dynamic JSON string with Hierarchical data using JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Ive a JSON like this

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "user1",
  "hasChildren": true,
  "parentID": 0,
  "children": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "user2",
      "paretnID": 1,
      "hasChildren": true,
      "children": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "user3",
      "parentID": 2,
      "hasChildren": false,
      "children": [

      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "user4",
      "parentID": 2,
      "hasChildren": false,
      "children": [

      ]
    }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "user5",
      "paretnID": 1,
      "hasChildren": true,
      "children": [
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "user6",
      "parentID": 5,
      "hasChildren": false,
      "children": [

      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "name": "user7",
      "parentID": 5,
      "hasChildren": false,
      "children": [

      ]
    }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "name": "user8",
      "paretnID": 1,
      "hasChildren": true,
      "children": [
    {
      "id": 9,
      "name": "user9",
      "parentID": 8,
      "hasChildren": false,
      "children": [

      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "name": "user10",
      "parentID": 8,
      "hasChildren": true,
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 11,
          "name": "user11",
          "parentID": 10,
          "hasChildren": false,
          "children": [

          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 12,
          "name": "user12",
          "parentID": 10,
          "hasChildren": false,
          "children": [

          ]
        }
      ]
    }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here as you can see its maintaining a hierarchy in each level in the children node. What my scenario is to convert this dynamic JSON as datatable rows

For deserilising this is how I tried

```
dynamic myJSON=jObject.parse(JSONstring);
```

but when I try `myJSON.id` its triggering an error like id not exists

What my plant is if children array has some elements, call another function to get its members and add to the datatable. But how can I get these fields from the dyanmic json string.

Comment: Correct typos `JObject.Parse`. Then it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
 public class Child2
 {
  public int id { get; set; }
  public string name { get; set; }
  public int parentID { get; set; }
  public bool hasChildren { get; set; }
  public List<object> children { get; set; }
 }

public class Child
 {
  public int id { get; set; }
  public string name { get; set; }
  public int paretnID { get; set; }
  public bool hasChildren { get; set; }
  public List<Child2> children { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
public int id { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
public bool hasChildren { get; set; }
public int parentID { get; set; }
public List<Child> children { get; set; }
}
```

then Deserialize

```
  var data=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(JSONstring);
```

then you can access data.id

You need to add reference Newtonsoft.json